# How to figure out why minio tenant is stuck in progressing in ArgoCD

Tags: cicd, minio, argocd

I have deployed a MinIO Tenant to my K8 cluster using ArgoCD and it's all "Synced", but it's stuck on "Progressing" and I can not see any reason for it and wondered how I can troubleshoot this.

When I check in ArgoCD, there are only one recourse marked as Progressing (the Tenant), it has no events but is marked as synced, there is no diff.

I can't see anything in the logs of any of the pods of ArgoCD and there are no unexpected logs from the Minio Tenant pods either.

The Tenant is working and everything is deployed correctly as far as I can tell.

the chart is:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: minio-observability-storage
home: https://min.io
icon: https://min.io/resources/img/logo/MINIO_wordmark.png
version: 0.0.0
appVersion: 0.0.0
type: application
description: A Helm chart for MinIO tenent

dependencies:
  - name: tenant
    repository: https://operator.min.io/
    version: 5.0.6
```

With the following Values:

```
tenant:
  tenant:
    # Tenant name
    name: minio-observability-staging
    ## Secret name that contains additional environment variable configurations.
    ## The secret is expected to have a key named config.env containing environment variables exports.
    configuration:
      name: minio-observability-staging-env-configuration
    pools:
      - servers: 4
        name: pool-0
        volumesPerServer: 4
        ## size specifies the capacity per volume
        size: 30Gi
        ## storageClass specifies the storage class name to be used for this pool
        storageClassName: ext-nas-storage-class
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 100
          runAsGroup: 1000
          runAsNonRoot: true
          fsGroup: 1000
    metrics:
      enabled: true
      port: 9000
      protocol: http
    features:
      bucketDNS: true
      domains:
        console: https://s3-console.staging.domain.io
        minio:
          - https://s3.staging.domain.io
    buckets:
      - name: observability-staging
        region: eu-west-1
    ## exposeServices defines the exposure of the MinIO object storage and Console services.
    exposeServices:

    # Tenant scrape configuration will be added to prometheus managed by the prometheus-operator.
    prometheusOperator: true

  ingress:
    api:
      enabled: true
      labels: {}
      annotations:
        cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
          client_max_body_size 0;
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          chunked_transfer_encoding off;
      tls:
        - secretName: minio-tenant-observability-general-tls
          hosts:
            - s3.staging.domain.io
      host: s3.staging.domain.io
      path: /
      pathType: Prefix

    console:
      enabled: true
      labels: {}
      annotations:
        cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
          client_max_body_size 0;
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          chunked_transfer_encoding off;
      tls:
        - secretName: minio-tenant-observability-con-general-tls
          hosts:
            - s3-console.staging.domain.io
      host: s3-console.staging.domain.io
      path: /
      pathType: Prefix
```